# Which ones are vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

What is the answer of this problem?

[image]

I feel confused because all feel like vector fields

A) Complex numbers can be seen as vectors of real numbers with two components.
B) Let f,g be functions from (0,1) to R that are twice differentiable. then $\alpha f$ and $f+g$ are in the set as well.
C) Consider $p (x^2+x+1)$ and $q (x^2+x+1)$. Then $p (x^2+x+1) + q (x^2+x+1) = (p+q) (x^2+x+1)$, and scalar multiplication works as well.
D) Triples of integers are vectors of integers with three components.
E) I am supposing it is this one since there are some sequences that are equivalent by appending zeros behind, and that makes the multiplication ill defined. But that feels like being *too literal*. Polynomials can also be defined as finite sequences and that does not break them.

Taken from [this blog](https://gowers.wordpress.com/2018/12/22/how-craig-barton-wishes-hed-taught-maths/).

Comment: Just to say:  there's a difference between a vector space and a vector field.  Your question only concerns vector spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fourth one is not a vector space: $\frac12(1,0,0)\notin\mathbb Z^3$, for instance.

Comment: Why would you pick the reals as the obvious scalar field? You could pick integers as scalars

Comment: @Jsevillamol A vector space has a field for scalars (if you want the integers as scalars you have to go to the more general idea of a "module")

Comment: @Jsevillamol Integers are not a field; the scalar field is implicit in the question, so you are force to assume that it includes at least $\mathbb Q$ for this problem.